# Redefinition error: Different .h files using the same class name

Tags: c++, class, scope, redefinition

I've created 2 header files. ListA.h and ListN.h

They both make their own use their own unique class List. When I compile my program (even though they have no way of knowing the other exists, it says the following error)

[image]
Im pretty sure it shouldnt be a redefinition, but it obviously is. Any help is appreciated.

---

**ListA.h**

```
#ifndef __LISTA_H_
#define __LISTA_H_
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class List{
        public:
              List(int = 0);
              List(const List&);
              ~List();
};   
#endif
```

**ListN.h**

```
#ifndef __LISTN_H_
#define __LISTN_H_
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class List{
        public:
              List(int = 10);
              List(const List&);
              ~List();
};    
#endif
```

---

**ListA.cpp**

```
#include "ListA.h"
using namespace std;

List::List(int mySize)
{
    //...
}
```

ListN.cpp

```
#include "ListN.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
List::List(int size)
{
    //...
}
```

---

**Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ListN.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    List myList;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They're both in the same project, that _might_ have something to do with it.

Comment: **[basic.def.odr]** "Given such an entity named D deﬁned in more than one translation unit, then each deﬁnition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens..." You violated this rule by having an entity named `List` defined differently in different translation units.

Answer (score 0):

When linker trying to link find the definition / symbol for List, it does found in two different obj file and hence linker givers error. In visual studio error number : [LNK2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72zdcz6f.aspx)

To solve this error, either:

1. To fix, add [/FORCE:MULTIPLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx) to the linker command line options
2. Add the classes in two different namespaces which will avoid this error.

**ListN.h**

> ```
> #ifndef __LIST_H_
> #define __LIST_H_
> #include <iostream>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> namespace ListN
> {
>   class List{
>   public:
>       List(int = 10);
>       List(const List&);
>   };
> }
>
> #endif
> ```

**ListN.cpp**

> ```
> #include "ListN.h"
> #include <iostream>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> namespace ListN
> {
>   List::List(int size)
>   {
>       //...
>   }
> }
> ```

**Main.cpp**

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include "ListN.h"
> int main()
> {
>   ListN::List myList;
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Now the main file says List was not declared in the scope

Comment: use namespace before user like for my case ListN::List. OR add using namespace ListN.

Answer (score 0):

Both cpp files are being compiled by the compiler. Thus, when the linker goes to link the files together, it gets confused, since there are multiple `List` classes.

To fix this, you could use namespaces, or you cold not expose at least one of the `List` classes.

---

Alternatively, if the idea was to be able to include **ListN.h** vs **ListA.h** for configuration purposes, this is the wrong way to do so. Either you should have a `#define` parameter for the header, or you should find some other way, such as through `#ifdef`. For example (I'm not 100% sure this would compile, but you get the idea):

**List.h**

```
#ifndef __LIST_H_
#define __LIST_H_

#ifndef LIST_PARAM
#define LIST_PARAM 0
#endif

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class List{
        public:
              List(int = LIST_PARAM);
              List(const List&);
              ~List();
};    
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#define LIST_PARAM 10
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    List myList;
    return 0;
}
```

I personally don't like this method; it is much better to just pass the value in to the constructor:

```
int main()
{
    List myList{ 10 };
    return 0;
}
```